# When Cancelling application using Ctrl+c, cpprestSDK giving exception and core Dump

Tags: coredump, sigint, casablanca, cpprest-sdk

the REST server is up and running but no request from any client
Now the user press Ctrl+c, then i get this exception.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pplx::invalid_operation'
  what():  then() cannot be called on a default constructed task.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

what does the above exception mean...??

I am not clear what the above exception means and why there is a core dump

please help

Comment: I assume that it may something to do with cancellation of task, but i am not entirely clear.

Comment: I have the location its not the client the server implementation that is causing the dump